# How to make a VM VirtualBox internet network the same on guest and host

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I was wondering if there is a way to make the internet network be recognized as the same as the host.

Truth is I don't know the specifics, the only thing I know is that a program is not recognizing it as the same network. Here is what is happening:

1. There is a software that is only available for macOS, and I have a Windows machine.
2. I made a VM on my Windows machine to host a macOS (Big Sur) machine and so far so good: It is successfully connected to the internet.
3. However, the software needs to be in the same network as my phone to recognize it. It does not recognize it.
4. I figured VM changes something on the network so when the software searches for devices on the same network it cannot find one.
5. I hope someone would have a fix for it.

Further information: My computer does not have WiFi and is an ethernet connection. I disconnected my ethernet and connected to my phone's internet via USB. Still, it is not recognized as two devices being in the same network.

I also tried sharing the MAC's internet to the phone but was not able to (I found on the internet that "Mac computers cannot tether with Android via USB.").

Now I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to make the internet network be recognized as the same as the host.

Virtual apps have two basic methods of allowing guests to have access to the Internet and to connect with other machines.

1. **NAT**:  Default where the Guest is on a different network but can still connect to other machines.
2. **Bridged**: Not usually default but puts the Guest machine on the same network as the Host Router and Host machine.

Bridged is the configuration you are looking for here.